# Android - Server socket connection with server codded in C?

Tags: android, c, sockets, client-server

Is it possible to open a socket connection between android (coded in Java) and the server (coded in C) ?

Can this work ? Is there something special to be aware of before implementing something like this ?

Answer (score 2):

With Java on Android, you can open a socket to any server on any platform written in any language, as long as the server is reachable with its network connection.  The usual IP-based networks don't care about the languages of the software that use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know that.